# Is it acceptable to ask what are the pre-requisites of a book?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Sometimes I find an advanced mathematics book that does not state the pre-requisites in the preface or introduction. Is it acceptable to ask about them here? Perhaps someone could take a look at the book on Google books or Amazon and suggest something.

Comment: With a bit of searching (e.g., google for [prerequisites book site:math.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=prerequisites+book+site:math.stackexchange.com)) you can find several such questions which were asked on math.SE. Of course, the site evolves and the fact that such questions have been well-received in the past does not mean that the same is still true.

Comment: A few examples: [Prerequisites for Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1080154), [Prerequisite books before Hungerford's Algebra?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1238076), [What are the prerequisites for Fulton's “Intersection Theory”?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/887698), [Jech's Set Theory logic prerequisites](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1182712), [What are the prerequisites to Jech's Set theory text?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/389212), [Background for reading Milnor's Morse Theory book](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/496046).

Comment: Yes, it is quite acceptable, especially since authors have been known to lie about prerequisites, claiming that once you can differentiate $\sin(x)$  you can read their elementary book on the applications of $(\infty,2)$-categories to heterotic chiral perturbation in quantum chromodynamics .

Answer (score 20):

I would say **Yes** to whether it is acceptable, in the sense that I will not vote to close it as off-topic,  for the following reasons:

- The question is arguably about mathematics and its education.
- The question is precise and limited in scope.
- While people may have some minor differences in opinion, questions of this type is largely answerable with a more-or-less correct answer.
- Questions of this type seeks "expert knowledge".
- Questions of this type could be useful for others (other people looking to read the same text).

---

On the other hand, I do not guarantee such a question would be well-received. For books that have extensive reviews on Amazon or google, or for books whose publishers conveniently included such information on their website (but not in the book), I may down-vote the question because the asker did not do the basic homework.

---

Lastly, to ask about prerequisites is to ask for a person to have read the book and to have remember the details and to contemplate what is needed as a background, both technically and pedagogically, for approaching that book. This is *not an easy question to answer*.

An easier question to answer would be:

> I am reading so-and-so's book *such and such*. In Chapter 3 I ran into an unfamiliar concept X. Can someone point me to in which subject X comes up and is taught and perhaps recommend a good book on that subject if my goal is to learn the theory discussed in *such and such*?

In other words, you don't always have to learn mathematics forwards. As a popular legend goes [Hobbes learned geometry by reading Euclid backwards](http://www.gogeometry.com/math_geometry_quotes/hobbes_thomas_math.html). A big chunk of self-learning is adapting to handle situations [like this](http://abstrusegoose.com/272) (don't click "next", click on the image).

Comment: I agree with the point about asking specific questions but disagree with downvoting because a book has extensive reviews on Amazon. I have in mind anything beyond highschool textbooks or calculus. There's a lot of reviews to shift through and I think the community here would offer a better opinion than on Amazon.

Comment: In support of @nayrb :  Look at http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Mathematical-Statistics-Its-Applications/dp/0321693949/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1433340040&sr=1-1&keywords=larsen+marx+statistics      That is a good book, most of the reviews are by students who obvioulsy hated it and learn you nothing about the books, a lot about what some students (dis)like.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: what does student like and dislikes have to do with a question about pre-requisites? In other words: if none of the reviews says anything about prerequisites, of course I will not count it against the OP. But if a large number of the reviews are of the form: "I am a second year graduate student and have studied subjects A, B, and C; and still I find the book incomprehensible." Then I would say that there gives some lower bound on the prerequisites.

Comment: @nayrb: perhaps what is not clear is my choice of the word "extensive". I meant it in the sense of "exhaustive, substantial, and thorough." The word "reviews" is in plural because I trust the opinions of several more than I trust that of one. Whereas you are thinking "many (possibly superficial) reviews" I intended "several detailed reviews" which, of course, will include information concerning prerequisites and such.